# RecyclerView can't click , doesn't work

Tags: java, android

The main problem is that `recyclerview` is not clickable. But I might use the wrong way to delete "!" when intent to the next pages, which is map. If I do this way the map only shows one user marker, but it is supposed to show two markers.

**In ListOnline.java**

```
private void updateList() {
    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, ListOnlineViewHolder>(
        User.class,
        R.layout.user_layout,
        ListOnlineViewHolder.class,
        counterRef
    ){

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ListOnlineViewHolder viewHolder, final User model, int position) {
            viewHolder.txtEmail.setText(model.getEmail());

            // item click recycler view
            viewHolder.itemClickListenener = new ItemClickListenener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                    //if model is current user , not set click event

                    if(!model.getEmail().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail()))
                    {
                        Intent map = new Intent(ListOnline.this, MapTracking.class);
                        map.putExtra("email",FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail());
                        map.putExtra("lat",mLastLocation.getLatitude());
                        map.putExtra("lng",mLastLocation.getLongitude());
                        startActivity(map);
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    };
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listOnline.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

After I change like this , i can be clickable but cant receive the friend marker.

```
if(model.getEmail().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail()))
```

means, i delete the '!' it can be intent to google map.

**In ListOnlineViewHolder.java**

```
public class ListOnlineViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    public TextView txtEmail;
    ItemClickListenener itemClickListenener;

    public ListOnlineViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtEmail = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_email);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setItemClickListenener(ItemClickListenener itemClickListenener){
        this.itemClickListenener = itemClickListenener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        itemClickListenener.onClick(view,getAdapterPosition());
    }}
```

**In ItemClickListenener Interface**

```
public interface ItemClickListenener {
    void onClick(View view, int position);
}
```

**In MapTracking**

```
 private void loadLocationForThisUser(String email) {
        Query user_location = locations.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email);

        user_location.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot postSnapShot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    Tracking tracking = postSnapShot.getValue(Tracking.class);

                    //add marker for friend location
                    LatLng friendLocation = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(tracking.getLat()),
                            Double.parseDouble(tracking.getLng()));

                    //create location from user coordinates
                    Location currentUser = new Location("");
                    currentUser.setLatitude(lat);
                    currentUser.setLongitude(lng);

                    //create location from friend coordinates
                    Location friend = new Location("");
                    friend.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(tracking.getLat()));
                    friend.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(tracking.getLng()));

                    //create function calculate distance between location
//                    distance(currentUser,friend);

                    //add friend marker on map
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(friendLocation)
                    .title(tracking.getEmail())
                            .snippet("Distance "+new DecimalFormat("#.#").format( distance(currentUser,friend)))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat,lng),12.0f));
                }
                //create marker for current user
                LatLng current = new LatLng(lat,lng);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(current).title(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Please help me, I spent almost a month to solve this project problem.

Pro, please, help me to see what is the problem, because I'm new to android. I'm most doing in Website server, PHP JAVAscript, HTML..

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask here. It seems your `RecyclerView` onClick listener is working fine. There's must be something wrong with the code logic of what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: @dr3k did you have any idea about it? I spent a month to solve the problem but fail i no idea about it.

Comment: Could you elaborate more about the problem that you are facing and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @dr3k My problem is cant click the recyclerview , but after i change to wrong way to delete the without"!" , It will become clickable but cant see friend marker in the map. U understand my statement? Sry because my english no well enough

Comment: I trying to create a friend real time tracking system

Comment: May I see this method: `loadLocationForThisUser` were used in your code?

Comment: @dr3k here you are : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51466060/10117843

Comment: @dr3k my target was only two users...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by delete

```
if(!model.getEmail().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail()))``
```